# Best schema type to use for a crowdfunded product?

Tags: schema.org, microdata, json-ld, products

On my website I maintain a list of crowdfunding projects related to tabletop gaming. The list is primarily board games, but will occasionally include dice, books, or even campaigns raising funds for conventions.

`https://www.meeplemountain.com/crowdfunding/` <-- for reference, but not auto-linked

What would be the best default schema to use for this sort of thing? My goal is to output an array of JSON LD for each product.

Comment: Outputting schema isn't your goal, or at least it shouldn't be.  Who is going to be using this schema and for what purpose?  There is no reason to use schema unless your goal is to make the data in your page machine readable for something.

Comment: Outputting schema is precisely my goal. I'm already displaying a visible list to users, now I'd like to include JSON LD to machines to consume, that's the only reason for microformats or JSON LD.

Comment: "machines" is way to general.  Which machines are you targeting and why?  Are you hoping for some rich snippet from search engines?  Do you have a request from a partner that wants access to your data?

Comment: Nope. The goal is to make this information more easily readable for search engines. But that is beside the point. The question I'm posing is "what is the most appropriate schema for a mix of listings"?

Comment: Google lists the schema that they use here: https://developers.google.com/search/docs/appearance/structured-data/search-gallery  There are a few types like bread crumbs schema that lots of sites can use, but there there are very few site niches for which Google has special schema support.  So even if you found a schema specific to your data set, it isn't going to help with making your data more easily readable for search engines.

Comment: Howdy Stephen, I'm certainly not trying to argue, but the entire point of schema, microformats, and JSON+LD, is solely to make it easier for search engines to digest your content in order to return it to people performing searches. If I can find a schema that matches my set it will 100% make my information easier for crawlers to interpret.

Comment: And just to be clear, I'm not looking for a "special" schema for my information, I'm just asking if anyone has an idea of a good generic schema I could use.